# Repeat code segment from certain cell

Tags: data-structures, gui-construction, infinite-loop

If I have a lot of code and wish to repeat it in a different cell, but with some variables changed, how do I do it? (without copying and pasting)

I tried using GoTo and Label but it did not recognize a label from a different cell

Comment: Suppose the code in the cell was `a = b x^2; c = d a^2;`, with `b` and `c` as parameters. Then define `f[b_, c_] := (a = b x^2; c = d a^2;)` and you can call the function `f` anywhere you like.

Comment: It didn't work. The Plots did not show. I need to see these Plots over and over again, with different parameters

Comment: In that case, we need a lot more details about what you're doing, because the way to do the thing correctly depends on what the code in the cell is doing. Is it calculating a result that you are storing in a variable? Is it making a plot? Is it making a series of plots? Is it doing all of those things? Those details are important. Anyway, try to wrap your `Plot` command with `Print` and try it again: `Print[Plot[ ... ]]`.

Comment: All of those things and more, There is a module defined too

Comment: Lisa, don't keep us guessing! Give us a practical example of such code, so that we can try to help you.

Comment: Greetings Lisa! To make the most of Mma.SE please **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Lisa, please edit the question to include the code you now have; we can reopen this once you've done so.